# Android GridView Get Position Of Touch In onScroll Event Listener

Tags: java, android, gridview, ontouchlistener, onscrolllistener

Im looking at the docs for the onScroll event listener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html

And I don't see an option for getting the position of the touch when a scroll event is occurring.

On iOS I could do

```
var pan = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer
var globalPoint = pan.locationInView(view)
```

However on Android I don't see the onScroll parameters with any values for the position of the touch event

```
@Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
            {
               //where you mr. touch position event? :(
               //oh touchevent.position, where art thou?
            }
```

One possible solution I'm considering is adding a view on TOP of the scrollview and listening for that touch position, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

**TL;DR** How do I get the position of a touch when the GridView was scrolled?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html  look over "drag drop" docs and "getX(), getY()" on a Drag_Location that u get from the event in the Listener().

Comment: Ahh cool I'll give this a read thanks. I've been trying to intercept the touch event in the fragment and thats been a mess of a nightmare, this looks like it has some potential

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully the solution turned out to be a lot less complex.

Just add an onTouchListener to the GridView and return false so it doesn't swallow the event.

```
_gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Position is " + event.getRawY());
        return false;
    }
});
```